# ssh -R binds to 127.0.0.1 only on remote

Tags: ssh, ip, ssh-tunnel, loopback

I'm running `ssh -N -f -R127.0.2.3:23000:127.1.2.3:23000 user@remote` , and I expect the tunnel on remote has opened on `127.0.2.3:23000`, but it only opens on `127.0.0.1:23000`, and it's inconvenient because I need to open several tunnels on remote, but listen to the same tcp port.

In the local machine, the tunnel points to the right ip address (127.1.2.3:23000).

I have tried creating several loopback devices on remote, to no avail.

The same is for Linux and Freebsd servers (openbsd-ssh)

So, why is ssh -R not binding to loopback ip's on remote other than 127.0.0.1?

Thank you.

(sorry for bad redacting :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

While the *local* optional bind address is at the control of SSH's client side (specified with `-L`/[`LocalForward`](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-client/ssh_config.5#LocalForward) or altered with `-g`/[`GatewayPorts`](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-client/ssh_config.5#GatewayPorts) in the *client*'s configuration), the *remote* optional bind address specified by the client with `-R`/[`RemoteForward`](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-client/ssh_config.5#RemoteForward) is at the control of SSH's *server* side with the *server* configuration [`GatewayPorts`](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-server/sshd_config.5#GatewayPorts). By default it's `no`. It should be set to `clientspecified` to allow the client to choose which address to bind to:

> `GatewayPorts`
>       Specifies whether remote hosts are allowed to connect to ports forwarded for the client. **By default, sshd(8) binds remote port
>   forwardings to the loopback address**. This prevents other remote hosts
>   from connecting to forwarded ports. `GatewayPorts` can be used to
>   specify that sshd should allow remote port forwardings to bind to
>   non-loopback addresses, thus allowing other hosts to connect. The
>   argument may be `no` to force remote port forwardings to be available to
>   the local host only, `yes` to force remote port forwardings to bind to
>   the wildcard address, or **`clientspecified` to allow the client to select
>   the address** to which the forwarding is bound. **The default is `no`**.

Moreover, the client's [`RemoteForward`](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-client/ssh_config.5#RemoteForward) entry tells likewise:

> [...]
>   If the bind_address is not specified, the default is to only bind to
>   loopback addresses. If the bind_address is ‘*’ or an empty string,
>   then the forwarding is requested to listen on all interfaces.
>   **Specifying a remote bind_address will only succeed if the server's
>   [`GatewayPorts`](https://manpages.debian.org/openssh-server/sshd_config.5#GatewayPorts) option is enabled (see sshd_config(5))**.

So you must be able to change the ssh's server configuration on the server (usually with root access), and add (or edit) this entry in the `sshd_config` file, so it shows:

```
GatewayPorts clientspecified
```

If you can't, you could use other available tools if present (or locally installable) on the server side to overcome this (quite weak) security limitation. For example [`socat`](https://manpages.debian.org/socat/socat.1#EXAMPLES), or `ssh` itself by using a `LocalForward` from the server to itself (even if it's uselessly adding a layer of encryption).

Comment: It works!, though I looked at this option before, but as it talked about "non loopback addresses" I just didn't try it out. I wonder if there should be an option to let you choose among loopback addresses only. Regards,

Comment: I admit the way it's written leads to think any loopback address should work, but reality tells otherwise. The check is there for example: https://salsa.debian.org/ssh-team/openssh/blob/buster/channels.c#L3285 . One could say it's plural: ipv4 and ipv6.

Comment: Usually, this file is `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Answer (score 1):

It turns out you can achieve it without changing `GatewayPorts` on *remote server*. The trick is to create another ssh connection on the remote server to forward

- On client side, same as your code

```
ssh -N -f -R127.0.2.3:23000:127.1.2.3:23000 user@remote
```

- On remote side, in addition to existing listening port `23000`, create a new connection from remote

```
# Should be on your remote node
ssh -g -L 23001:localhost:23000 user@remote_ip
```

```
                 Remote         
--------         |-------------------------------------------------
|client|-------->| Port 23000 ----    // (127.0.0.1:23000  LISTEN)
--------         |                |
                 | Port 23001 <---    // (0.0.0.0:23001    LISTEN)
                 |--------------------------------------------------
```

Reference:
Kudo to @FaST4 : https://askubuntu.com/a/789275/523440